# EV3 IDE flickering

Tags: ev3, software, ev3-g, mac

I'm using the Mindstorms IDE for EV3 on OSX.
Everytime I'm moving the cursor the screen starts to flicker.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3JkonowmD0&feature=youtu.be .

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After all rebooting the Mac stopped the flickering.

However I reinstalled Silverlight and the Mindstorms IDE before rebooting. So I'm not 100% sure what part of the procedure solved the problem.